# Joining a string with input fields = one value

Tags: php

how can I get this result as a value of **LUC-1701-000005** field I made ..

[image]

I get the current value from one field (`$value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c26'];`), but I want to make it easier for customers to not enter those LUCs ... than just numbers..

current code looks like this ..

```
for($I=0; $I<= 5; $I++){
if($I == 0){
    $value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c26'];                        
}
else if($I == 1){           
    $value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c30'];                                         
}
else if($I == 2){
    $value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c34'];
}
else if($I == 3){
    $value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c44'];
}
else if($I == 4){
    $value = $_POST['wpuef_options']['c50'];
}
```

this is something I need ..but this is not correct ..

```
$value = "LUC-" + $_POST['wpuef_options']['c26'] + "-" + $_POST['wpuef_options']['c23'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = "LUC-" . $_POST['wpuef_options']['c26'] . "-" . $_POST['wpuef_options']['c23'];
```

You are using `+` for concatenation, which is wrong, in PHP it is just `.` .